# Azure AD B2C :: Roles claim is missing in access token

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-ad-b2c

I have two registered applications in Azure AD B2C: azure functions application and frontend spa application.
I call azure functions from frontend app and use implicit authorization flow.
I use MSAL npm package to request access token.

I followed this article to setup roles for users:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps

But access_token I receive in Frontend app is missing "roles" claim, as well as id_token.
Here is access token I receive:

```js
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "X5eXk4xyojNFum1kl2Ytv8dlNP4-c57dO6QGTVBwaNk"
}.{
  "iss": "https://<tenant_name>.b2clogin.com/<id>/v2.0/",
  "exp": 1595333452,
  "nbf": 1595329852,
  "aud": "3d6123b2-b436-46c0-bcde-e0b61b0ad827",
  "oid": "e98c46c4-f13d-428e-9b7d-28ba3abeb060",
  "sub": "e98c46c4-f13d-428e-9b7d-28ba3abeb060",
  "name": "Basic User",
  "emails": [
    "basicuser@gmail.com"
  ],
  "tfp": "B2C_1_signin_v2",
  "nonce": "a70eece3-31d2-4cc3-8abb-0a56a95d4ba1",
  "scp": "demo.read",
  "azp": "d7787de1-6642-409f-b0b9-2f5608476367",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "iat": 1595329852
}.[Signature]
```

Why there are no roles in it?

Comment: I marked your answer with checkmark but I got a message "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score".

Comment: Thank You TanyaMy for the vote. You can also accept the answer if it was helpful,( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application roles are not currently supported in Azure AD B2C.

You can raise user voice for your request [Azure feedback portal](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory) or vote for an [existing one](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10123836-get-user-membership-groups-in-the-claims-with-ad-b).

For now, you can call MS Graph from AAD B2C custom policy, there is an ability to call APIs in Custom Policy using OAuth client credentials.

You can query the users group membership and then return the data back to B2C policy directly, and issue it into the token

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api#oauth2-bearer-authentication

Then use this to get the data from MS Graph

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-claims-exchange

or

You need to use either groups to manage this, or create an AAD App inside the B2C tenant and do the App Role assignments there. Then during the B2C policy execution, call a REST API to query the roles for the user and insert them into the B2C token. You need to use custom policy for this one. Please refer [github sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/relying-party-rbac) similar to this

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What do you mean by _create an AAD App inside the B2C tenant_ ? Is it a custom API or just insert a code somewhere?

Comment: App need to be registered under b2c tenant. Create a Custom API which queries the roles of the user and you need to call this custom API from the custom policy.

Comment: There is an existing feature request for this that you can vote on. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/42861216-add-app-roles-to-azure-ad-b2c-to-support-applicati

Comment: I have an `Azure AD` app registration _within_ my `Azure AD B2C` tenant, and in the `Manage` menu on the app registration page there is NO `App roles` menu item (like there is in a 'normal' Azure AD tenant app registration page).

Comment: However, I went to `Azure AD` within my `Azure AD B2C` tenant, clicked on `Enterprise Applications` > `Application Type:  All Applications` > clicked on my application > `Users and Groups`. There is text at top of page that says 'Assign users and groups to app-roles for your application here. To create new app-roles for this application, use the `application registration`'. When I click on the link, it loads a page where u CAN create an app role - URL is like this: `https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationMenuBlade/~/AppRoles/appId/***/defaultBlade/AppRoles`

Comment: After I added the `app role`, I was able to assign the role to `Azure AD B2C` tenant users following the steps here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#assign-users-and-groups-to-roles

Comment: So my above comments show how to 1) create an app-role and 2) assign the app-role to an Azure AD B2C user. I am now trying to figure out the easiest, out of the box, way to return the user's roles in the identity token after a successful login. There seem to be many approaches out there but they all look quite complicated (custom policies, calls to graph api etc), so hopefully I will stumble across a simple solution soon.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can remember, B2C doesn't support Role claims. I've had to make use of a custom claim in the past and [Sven Glöckner has written an article](https://dev.to/sven5/using-custom-claims-for-azure-ad-b2c-roles-720) that describes something similar to what I've done.

In my case, I've added the role claim value to default to 'appMember', which was like the main role for a user on the site and if he had a UPN extension of our company, he would get a role like 'internalUser'. This is how we distinguished the permissions that would apply to the security trimming and downstream calls.

Comment: I successfully implemented a custom role claim as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-user-flow#using-custom-attribute-with-ms-graph-api B2C doesn't support string[] as a datatype for custom attributes so I'm simply using a string type and then the claim value is comma-separated roles

Comment: Where and how can an admin change the claim value in the Azure Portal later? E.g. from 'appMember' to 'internalUser'? This is not described in the linked article by Sven Glöckner.

Comment: Also, I am not sure about the difference between user attributes and claims in this answer. As far as I know I can only create user attrributes which then can be selected as claims that are returned in the token. How would I "create" a claim and set the default value to e.g. 'appMember'?